# How to use pr_cont to continue a previous log message in the same line?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

**[Question]**
Recently I did some work on the Linux kernel, and want to use 'print' to continue a previous log message in the same line. So I tried to use pr_cont in <linux/kernel.h> to replace printk in the function.

The code is here:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>

typedef struct {
    TEST_PRINTF    printf;
    TEST_UDELAY    udelay;
    TEST_MALLOC    malloc;
    TEST_FREE      free;
} TEST_INIT_PARAM_T;

static int __init test_init(void) {
    TEST_INIT_PARAM_T my_init_param = { 0 };

    /* The problem is here */
    my_init_param.printf = pr_cont;
    my_init_param.udelya = my_udelay;
    my_init_param.malloc = my_malloc;
    my_init_param.free = my_free;

    my_init(&my_init_param);

    ....
}
```

and GCC shows an error: 'pr_cont' undeclared (first use in this function). However, if use

```
my_init_param.printf = printk;
```

and this will be ok.

I have also tried using

```
void test_printk(some_variables) {
    printk(KERN_CONT some_variables)
}
```

And make `my_init_param.printf = test_printk`.
But I don't know what the 'some_variable' should be?

Also, I really want to know why the equation `my_init_param.printf = pr_cont` is wrong?

**[Attempt]**
I have realized that the true reason why the equation
`my_init_param.printf = pr_cont;`doesn't hold. Just like I can't define `a = int b`. So I add typedef as below

```
typedef int
(*TEST_PRINTK)(
    const char *fmt,
    ...);

TEST_PRINTK test_pr_cont;

#define test_pr_cont(fmt, ...) \
    printk(KERN_CONT fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Then the equation`my_init_param.printf = test_pr_cont;`can pass the GCC.

However, other functions called this 'print' cannot print anything.

Answer (score 0):

> why the [expression] my_init_param.printf = pr_cont is wrong?

Because `pr_cont` is a macro, it's not a function. Sole identifier `pr_cont` does not exist, only the call `pr_cont( the call )` will be expanded to the call to `printk` by preprocessor. `pr_cont` is a function-like macro.

> How to use pr_cont to continue a previous log message in the same line?

Write `pr_cont` with your message after another `pr_*` or `printk` above without a newline on the end. There are endless examples in kernel, browse them. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/csky/kernel/traps.c#L124

Comment: Thank you, sir. But how can I make the equation ```my_init_param.printf = xxx;``` holds? Since I can not use a macro like pr_cont.

Comment: You can do `my_init_param.printf = printk;`. You can define a function

Comment: Excuse me, sir. But printk will start a new line, so I guess I should define a new function, i.e. test_printk, however, It is hard for me to define a 'print' related function, since in this kernel I can't include <stdarg.h> to define a function like 
```
int printf (const char *fmt, ...) { 
    va_list args;
    int ret_val;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    ret_val = ...

    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: @Hastings There is `int vprintk(const char *fmt, va_list args);` in the kernel. Callers of your function will need to add `KERN_CONT` before the literal format string to allow string literal concatenation to work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But a vprintk() function seems to exist in the kernel. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/vprintk